# Noobie at IC, need help with basic circuit that isn't returning correct values

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

Okay, first of, I'm a complete newbie at ICs and circuits and I'm doing this for a school project. I request answers to be in laymans terms and not proper, complicated terms. For my first demonstration, I want to hook an LED to a NOT-Gate. I have the 7404 IC, and I'm using pin 1 and input and pin 2 as output. My power source is a +9V and therefore I've connected a 100 ohm resistor between input A and the power source and I've put anther resistor between output B (or Y) and the LED.

The diagram is as follows:

Now the problem is, why is the LED ALWAYS on when its connected to a power source regardless of the switch being on/off (when its on, the led should switch off, right, since B = NOT A)? So why is it always on? I'm not sure how exactly you connect a 6-pin switch, but I'm connecting two pins that are adjacent:

X X O

O O O

where X and X symbolize the connected pins. Connected as in they have wires connected to 
them, and there wires are not connected to each other (as in a switch, really cant explain it better) this seems to work fine in a normal – battery-switch–bulb circuit. (On/Off is working so I know the switch isn't the problem, and neither does the rest of the circuit seem to be). Also, I noticed, if I connect the +ve from the bulb to ANY pin from 1-13 (including ground) the bulb lights up. I've tried this with 2 gates (both NOT) so I know the problem isn’t in the gates. So where is it?

Top-down view:  [image]

Circuit view: [image]

I know you really can't see the wires but if you look closely you may, I guess.
And finally, circuit concept: (I suck at paint xD). Btw the RED is +ve and the black is -ve.

[image]

Comment: What's the exact part number of your chip? The SN7404 is designed to be powered from 5V, not 9V. 9V applied to the VCC terminal may well damage it.

Comment: Its numbered 74F04N. I also used a resistor for that.

Comment: I think maybe you have a misunderstanding of what resistors do. Simply placing a resistor between the supply and the VCC pin won't actually drop the voltage at all. Although resistors do cause a volttage drop when current is flowing (with the relationship V = IR), you can't make any assumptions about how much current the IC will draw. The [SN74F04N datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdfs037a/sdfs037a.pdf) gives the absolute maximum voltage at VCC as 7V, and nominal as 5V. When you first connect the battery to the chip, you're applying 9V to Vcc.

Comment: Well, this helps my confusion - when i tried to use ohm's law to calculate the voltage change i was miffed, since all my knowledge told me it wouldnt change the PD, only the current. So i i use a +6V IN, would that resolve the problem?

Comment: Although the maximum rating is 7V, the operating voltage range is 4.5 to 5.5V. It may work with 6V, but it would be operating outside of the recommended limits. You have probably damaged your IC, so you'll likely need to replace it with a new one once you've fixed the circuit.

Comment: Would using a 100ohm resistor with the 6V help?

Comment: Again, a resistor *does not reduce the voltage* unless there is current flowing. You can't make any assumptions about the current drawn by the IC. As Nick Williams said below, you could use a diode to provide a voltage drop of around 0.7V, or you could just power the IC from 6V (which would probably work but reduce the life of the IC).

Comment: Show a real schematic of what exactly you hooked up.  Also clean up your post while you're at it.  Show some respect and use real words.  The first 4 words of your question make a annoying first impression and put people the mindset to look for other problems instead of wanting to give you some slack.  You wouldn't hand in homework like this, so you are saying we don't deserve the same respect your teachers do.  No thanks, and -1 for the sloppiness.

Comment: Im sorry, but i havent slept in forever and im kind of frustrated. I didnt want to write this in legal language, neither was i up to it. This is my first day working with circuits - the theory and the practical work. It took me hours to set this stuff up , i messed up twice, and its really frustrating. Not to mention i have other work piled up. I wrote this as fast and coherently as i could, i can upload a better schematic, but i expect you to bear with me.

Comment: No, we're not going to "bear with you" to ignore sloppiness.  Note that this has nothing to do with your level of electronics knowledge.  If you're not ready to communicate properly, don't post here.  You have no right to inflict crap on us because you're frustrated, this is your first day on the problem, setup took you a long time, you haven't slept, or you spilled your coffee.  None of these are relevant issues, and you are still asking the volunteers here to provide you with free help regardless.  If you can't show the proper respect, you don't belong here.

Comment: Well, in all fairness, nobody is holding a gun to your head , forcing you to help me. If you dont like my post, then you need not rant about it. If you arent here to help or dont want to or are repulsed by the tyops/ writing style, complaining doesnt help me, it doesnt help you. If youre ready to help, then please do, i appreciate it, if youre not ready to help and only ready to whine, then lets agree to disagree and move on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming in this case you are using the SN7404 NOT IC. The datasheet is shown here:
[SN7404 Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf)

Right now I see three big issues.

**Issue 1**

The first issue is in regards to the comment that user LeoR made. The SN7404 (if that is indeed, the IC you are using) takes 5V, not 9V.

Here is the operating ranges per datasheet:
[image]

**Issue 2**

You didn't mention that you connected the 7404 to ground, nor does your drawing show that your ground is hooked up.

The SN7404 must be grounded for the circuit to work.

**Issue 3**

Your switch does not have a pull down resistor to pull the input node to ground when your switch is open. When your switch is open, the input node (the input to the NOT gate) is left floating.

I drew up a really quick schematic to demonstrate the pull down:
[image]

The NOT gate is obviously the IC, but there is a 10K resistor connected to the input node of the NOT gate so that when the switch is open, the node is pulled down to ground. With this arrangement, pressing the switch will turn the LED off, while opening the switch will turn the LED on.

You must add this resistor (doesn't have to be 10K, anywhere from 5K to 20K should be OK) for the logic to work.

You can ignore the wires grounding the switch here, they aren't necessary for you. But you mentioned that you don't know which pins of the switch you need to connect. You must use a multimeter to test continuity (or set to measure resistance) between the two pins to be sure. If the switch is closed, the continuity is there (resistance is 0Ohms), if the switch is open, there is no continuity (resistance is infinite).

Comment: If i changed my source to just 4.5v, no resistors , would the circuit work? (My schematic) or would i still need to ground the IC. Im really new to this so i dont know how to really do any of that. ive made logic gates in minecraft :p , but this is my first time. And google didnt help on grounding the IC (i know i cant believe it either). So the scematic i made, just with the power source changed to an array of 3 AA cells in series would work?

Comment: Grounding the IC = connecting *all* the pins marked "GND" to 0V. In this case 0V is the negative side of the battery and there is only one GND pin.

Comment: 3 AAs may be enough if you're lucky: but you are below the minimum operating voltage with 4.5V, so I wouldn't count on it. The correct thing to do would be to regulate the voltage, also many wall adapters use 5V so you could go with that. However, since this is a learning activity, and I'm not sure how capable you are: perhaps try 4 AAs in series to get 6V. Yes, you may fry the IC; yes, this is not the right thing to do but at least you can see a functioning application of a logic gate in the real world, if not for a short amount of time.

Comment: @t3hCrush3r Also I'd like to mention, if you are discouraged right now: please do not be. There may be a steep learning curve when first entering circuits, but the understanding WILL come. Go over the datasheet I linked.

Comment: Haha, i actually dont mind, its fun. IM only doing it because i want to, its optional, so dont worry, im not discouraged. Plus im thinking of electrical as a possible major, so no way im backing down. Well, if i used a 6V battery and a 100Ohm resistor, would that bring it down to a 4.5-5.5V range that could work? 
Btw your datasheet: www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdfs037a/sdfs037a.pdf

Comment: The resistor probably won't work. Yes, voltage does drop across a resistor, but you know that V = IR. The current to the 7404 will be small, so the drop will be minimal. If you use a large resistor,you may get the voltage down. A better method would be to use a diode instead of a resistor. A diode usually has a voltage drop of 0.7V, which would get you really close to your voltage range. If this isn't feasible, try the 6V and the resistor; as mentioned before, seeing how this is a learning project, all we really care about is the concept of the logic gate, not how to build a power supply unit.

Comment: @NickWilliams: the circuit you show, with a 10K pull-down resistor, is fine for CMOS logic, but won't work with the 74F04 the OP says he is using, as the 74F04 input needs to source 0.6 mA to be recognized as a low.

Comment: AAGH. I wish i had network theorems this year.
The +6v is a no go, im gonna try and hook it to a resistor and ground it. As of now: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10sezrk&s=8#.U5navyhvTec , it isnt returning false.

Comment: I have as of now, 6V courtesy of 4 AA's in series, a 6V into my VCC, a 6V into my PIN 1 (IN A) , Pin 7 out to my -ve , a led connected with a 100ohm resistor the the battery -ve, and with PIN B(out B) on its positive. Now regardless of a being connected or not, the LED is always on. It just stutters a bit when i turn a on or off. To sum up - my IC has +6V into VCC and A, is grounded by attaching pin 7 to the -ve of my battery, and the output from B is always true, regardless of whether a is on or off. –

Comment: @t3hCrush3r you're attaching A (the NOT input) to power and the LED is still on? That can't be right. Double check the pinout on the IC with the datasheet. Try other NOT gates, I think the 7404 has 6 or so.

Comment: ^ I was gonna, but ive tried two chipsets. Infact, my AND gate is giving the same blasted result. Except, when i have A AND B c is brightly lit, but if A and B are off, c is dimly lit. Its SOME progress. I havent yet grounded the AND, let me try that, let me try another not gate on the IC and i also tried adding upto 2 resistors into the 6V input(both of 100ohm), and they make like NO difference.

Comment: This might help: same result with grounding, btw,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ztrxGSwDd0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Can this be caused because im using uninsulated wire?

Comment: No matter what i do, ground it, unground it, turn a and b on, off, it always gives a light on the LED form ANY pin.

Answer (score 1):

The 74F04 requires power (6 volts would work - **definitely not 9 volts!**) on pin 14 and ground on pin 7.

Bipolar TTL parts (74xx, 74LSxx, 74Fxx - basically anything without a "C" in the middle of the part number) will source current from the input pin - in the case of the 74F04, the input source current for a Low is 0.6 mA.  Bcause of this relatively high source current, it is traditional to connect a switch between the input pin and ground, and a pull-up resistor (5K1 or so) to Vcc.

The circuit given in another answer, with the switch to Vcc and a 10K resistor to ground, will work with CMOS parts (74C, 74AC, etc.) as their inputs source or sink virtually no current, but it definitely won't work with the 74F04, as the 10K won't pull the input anywhere near a Low level.

Comment: I have as of now, 6V courtesy of 4 AA's in series, a 6V into my VCC, a 6V into my PIN 1 (IN A) , Pin 7 out to my -ve , a led connected with a  100ohm resistor the the battery -ve, and with PIN B(out B) on its positive. Now regardless of a being connected or not, the LED is always on. It just stutters a bit when i turn a on or off. To sum up - my IC has +6V into VCC and A, is grounded by attaching pin 7 to the -ve of my battery, and the output from B is always true, regardless of whether a is on or off.

Comment: Since you previously applied 9 volts to the chip, you have quite probably killed it.  Try a new 74F04.

Comment: I did. I even tried a FRESH AND chip 7408.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ztrxGSwDd0&feature=youtu.be
Maybe its the uninsulated wire?

Comment: No matter what i do, ground it, unground it, turn a and b on, off, it always gives a light on the LED form ANY pin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but with your schematic, it looks like when the switch is closed you are shorting the chip of it's VCC and the IC appears to have no GND connected either.  I'm not entirely confident in this answer though.  Good luck!

Comment: And how would i rectify this? And why exactly am i "shorting" it? Im really not looking for explanations as much as solutions.

Comment: Do you have pin 7 grounded?

Comment: Nope. Not sure how i do that.

Comment: Google isnt helping either.

Comment: Try connecting Pin 7 to the negative on supply.

Comment: Ill do that and get back

Comment: Now the circuit doesnt show true.
Pin no 2 and 3 are soldered together, could that be the cause?

Comment: No that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Try taking some wire and just touch it to both leads of that resistor you have going to your VCC, "Shorting it," and see if that fixes your issue.  That will make all your voltages uniform, because as it is you have 4.5V to VCC and 9V going through the gate.  The resistor is going to divide the voltage in half to the VCC that's how you end up with 4.5V.

Comment: If you have a spare cell phone charger you can cut the plug off and use the positive/negative leads.  Since most chargers are USB, they supply 5VDC.

Comment: But then ill need a 240V AC as the real input. Which i cant get in school where im supposed to demonstrate it.